# How to solve this determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[image: Determinent]

How do I solve this determinant?

Comment: What have you tried, @LiziPizi?

Comment: Try evaluating it directly on the 3-by-3 version, then the 4-by-4 version, then the 5-by-5 version.  Can you generalize?

Comment: @BrianTung yes I can generalize it but should I prove it with induction?

Answer (score 1):

The determinant of a tridiagonal matrix can be calculated via the recurrence $f_n= af_{n-1} -cbf_{n-2}$ with $f_0=1$ and $f_1=a$

in this case $a=3,b=1,c=2$

so the recurrence relation is $f_n=3f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2}$